# What is the maximum store discount I can get?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm currently sitting at a 10% discount from Intel upgrades (2x 5% discount), but I'd like to know what the maximum potential discount is. Considering [weapons and mods carry over](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53717/160) into New Game+, what I'd like to do is just buy up as much as I can afford as I near the end of the game so my squaddies will be better kitted out for Insanity (I don't use weapons much myself on my Vanguard).

Is 10% the maximum? I've got *Priority: Horizon* in my Journal as my next mission, and the galaxy is currently 100% scanned.

Comment: I'm fairly certain 10% is the max, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm foing the same thing so I can use those intel for combat upgrades next round

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10 is the maximum to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I have 15% already, it's possible you missed one possibility in ardat-yakshi monastery...

Answer (score 0):

10 is the maximum i think. good luck!