# What exactly can I keep in second play-through of ME3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a new game plus for Mass Effect 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53623/is-there-a-new-game-plus-for-mass-effect-3)

Sorry if this is a duplicate.  I checked but I didn't see this answered.  I'm planning to wait for the Mass Effect 3 extended cut DLC later this summer but would like some confirmation on a few things:

- Can I play through Mass Effect 3 again with my same character?
- If so, what exactly can I keep (as far as stats) on the second play-through?

Thanks.

Comment: (The answer is covered in the above question)